# Modal window promise in Angular resolves twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the modal directive in angular and capturing when the modal closes using the result promise. For some reason the promise is resolving twice even though I only have one instance of the modal.

Here is the code for setting up the modal and the promise:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: '/views/test.html',
    controller: 'Test'
});

modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    $scope.start();
});
```

This brings up the modal and uses the following basic controller:

```
angular.module('module')
    .controller('Test', function($scope, $interval, $modalInstance) {

        $scope.timeLeft = 15;
        var timer = $interval(function() {
            if($scope.timeLeft == 0){
                $modalInstance.close();
            } else {
                $scope.timeLeft--;
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Not sure why but the promise is resolving twice. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the bootstrap modal directive? https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal

Comment: Yes I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: OK.  Edited the tags for this question.  The proper terminology is that "promises are resolved". They are not "executed". And a promise can only be resolved once (by design).  So, there are two possibilities. Either, you are getting an extra handler added to your promise (that calls start again), or you have 2 promises that are each resolving and invoking start().  Can you include the code for start() and the module code that surrounds the creation of `modalInstance`?

Comment: Ah I figured it out, the problem is not with any of the code i have above :/. Apparently routeProvider is initializing my controller twice which causes two modalInstances to be created. I am currently working on a fix. Thanks for the tip on terminology. JavaScript is still pretty new to me.

Comment: As controller is initializing twice - remove direcive `ng-controller="Test"` from the template.

Comment: Yeah that is what I ended up doing. Thanks!